# Get Each Item In An Array From User Input

Tags: php

I would like to get each item in an array from user input form. The user will input numbers from a single input field separated by space (1 2 3 4) then I get this input and replace the space with commas (1,2,3,4) and add this variable to array however the results returned by $number seems to return the entire value as a single number like this:

```
1,2,3,4
```

And not like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

code:

```
<?php

  $inp_results =$_POST['inp_results'];
  $inp_results_comma = str_replace(' ', ',', $inp_results);
  $number_in_results = array($inp_results_comma); 

  foreach ($number_in_results as $number)
  {
    echo "$number</br>";
  }
```

Comment: Why not just [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on white spaces?

Comment: `$string = '1 2 3 4'; $result = explode(' ',$string); foreach ($result as $number) {
echo "$number</br>";
}` Just it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$inp_results = $_POST['inp_results'];
$number_array = explode(' ', $inp_results);
foreach ($number_array as $number) {
    echo "$number</br>";
}
```